# ID of the child views in a custom view are same in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view `ValueSelectorView` which contains two buttons to increment and decrement value and an EditText to display that value. In my activity, I am using this view three times. My concern here is with the child views that their `id` is always the same when checked in logs. Due to this, the resultant value comes out to be incorrect.

I have looked over on StackOverflow and found out that some of them have faced the same issue and they are trying to solve it by manually altering the id of the child views using `setId`. Tried inflating the child views using a couple of different methods but the issue still persists

This is my custom view class

```
package eu.siacs.conversations.ui.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import eu.siacs.conversations.Config;
import eu.siacs.conversations.R;

public class ValueSelectorView extends RelativeLayout {

    View rootView;
    EditText valueTextView;
    View minusButton;
    View plusButton;

    private int minValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int maxValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public ValueSelectorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public ValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.value_selector, this, true);
        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this view is -->" + getResources().getResourceEntryName(rootView.getId()));
        valueTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.valueTextView);

        minusButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        plusButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);

        minusButton.setOnClickListener(v -> decrementValue());

        plusButton.setOnClickListener(v -> incrementValue());

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ValueSelectorView,0,0);
        int defaultVaue = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ValueSelectorView_defaultValue,0);
        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 0 -->" + valueTextView.getId());
//        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this Minus Button is 0 -->" + minusButton.getId());
//        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this Add Button is 0 -->" + plusButton.getId());
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(defaultVaue));

        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    public void setDefaultValue(int value) {
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public int getMinValue() {
        return minValue;
    }

    public void setMinValue(int minValue) {
        this.minValue = minValue;
    }

    public int getMaxValue() {
        return maxValue;
    }

    public void setMaxValue(int maxValue) {
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());
    }

    /*public void setValue(int newValue) {
        int value = newValue;
        if(newValue < minValue) {
            value = minValue;
        } else if (newValue > maxValue) {
            value = maxValue;
        }
        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 1 -->" + valueTextView.getId());
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }*/

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    private void incrementValue() {

        int currentVal = Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());
        if(currentVal < maxValue) {
            Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 2-->" + valueTextView.getId());
            valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentVal + 1));
        }
    }

    private void decrementValue() {
        int currentVal = Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());
        if(currentVal > minValue) {
            Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 3-->" + valueTextView.getId());
            valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentVal - 1));
        }
    }


}
```

This is how I use it in my activity XML.

```
<eu.siacs.conversations.ui.widget.ValueSelectorView
                android:id="@+id/value_selector_nights"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin4"
                app:defaultValue="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<eu.siacs.conversations.ui.widget.ValueSelectorView
                    android:id="@+id/value_selector_adults"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin4"
                    app:defaultValue="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<eu.siacs.conversations.ui.widget.ValueSelectorView
                    android:id="@+id/value_selector_children"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:defaultValue="0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Below are the logs:

```
****view testr**** id of this view is -->value_selector_nights
****view testr**** id of this TextView is 0 -->2131297384
****view testr**** id of this view is -->value_selector_adults
****view testr**** id of this TextView is 0 -->2131297384
****view testr**** id of this view is -->value_selector_children
****view testr**** id of this TextView is 0 -->2131297384
```

I would like to understand how it works internally and find a solution for the same. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the resultant value comes out to be incorrect"? Do you mean that your `defaultValue` attribute isn't working? Or that the plus/minus buttons don't work as expected? Or that the values don't restore correctly after a configuration change, like a device rotation? Something else?

Comment: So, this is inside a fragment which is in the view pager. Whenever I update the value using the increment and decrement buttons and then switch the tabs in view pager, this value gets reset. For example:
The values before switching tabs
nights = 5
adults = 4
children = 3
The values after switching tabs will be
nights = 5
adults = 5
children = 5

Comment: As you can see in XML that my default values are 1,1 and 0 for nights, adults and children respectively. Now when I switch the tabs without changing the values from the increment and decrement button, the value gets reset to 0,0 and 0. When I started debugging, I came to know that the ID of the child views are same.

Comment: OK, yeah, you've hit on the root cause of the issue. It's not inherently wrong to have duplicate IDs in a hierarchy, otherwise things like `ListView` wouldn't work. The problem is with restoring state, and even some framework compound `View`s have the same issue as you're seeing; e.g., `SearchView` will do the same thing if you have more than one. You'll have to handle saving and restoring state for your custom `View`. You could do this in the `Activity`'s `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, but it's arguably better to do it internally. Lemme see if I can find an example.

Comment: Is this what you are referring :
https://github.com/paveldudka/ViewStateSaveDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/trickyandroid/com/funwithstate/MyCustomLayout.java

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: I tried the code mentioned in the tutorial, This does not fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I was just typing out this comment: That example isn't quite comparable to your custom `View`. You're likely going to have to turn off the automatic save/restore for the `EditText`s. You can do that simply by adding `android:saveEnabled="false"` to the `<EditText>` in the layout.

Comment: I just ran a quick test with the posted code, and the save/restore modifications, and it's working for me. Here's the layout change and the code additions I made: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10gBj7LcYlChrYWwk3Jy5SWetf37gdHOi/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: Yes, now I can see the expected behavior. Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others, who are facing the same issue.

My updated code is:

```
package eu.siacs.conversations.ui.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import eu.siacs.conversations.Config;
import eu.siacs.conversations.R;

public class ValueSelectorView extends RelativeLayout {

    View rootView;
    EditText valueTextView;
    View minusButton;
    View plusButton;
    private int customState;

    private int minValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int maxValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    public ValueSelectorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public ValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ValueSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.value_selector, this, true);
        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this view is -->" + getResources().getResourceEntryName(rootView.getId()));
        valueTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.valueTextView);

        minusButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        plusButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);

        minusButton.setOnClickListener(v -> decrementValue());

        plusButton.setOnClickListener(v -> incrementValue());

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ValueSelectorView,0,0);
        int defaultVaue = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ValueSelectorView_defaultValue,0);
        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 0 -->" + valueTextView.getId());
//        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this Minus Button is 0 -->" + minusButton.getId());
//        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this Add Button is 0 -->" + plusButton.getId());
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(defaultVaue));

        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    public void setDefaultValue(int value) {
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public int getMinValue() {
        return minValue;
    }

    public void setMinValue(int minValue) {
        this.minValue = minValue;
    }

    public int getMaxValue() {
        return maxValue;
    }

    public void setMaxValue(int maxValue) {
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());
    }

    /*public void setValue(int newValue) {
        int value = newValue;
        if(newValue < minValue) {
            value = minValue;
        } else if (newValue > maxValue) {
            value = maxValue;
        }
        Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 1 -->" + valueTextView.getId());
        valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }*/

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    private void incrementValue() {

        int currentVal = Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());
        if(currentVal < maxValue) {
            Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 2-->" + valueTextView.getId());
            valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentVal + 1));
        }
    }

    private void decrementValue() {
        int currentVal = Integer.valueOf(valueTextView.getText().toString());
        if(currentVal > minValue) {
            Log.i(Config.LOGTAG, "****view testr**** id of this TextView is 3-->" + valueTextView.getId());
            valueTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentVal - 1));
        }
    }

    public void setCustomState(int customState) {
        this.customState = customState;
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.value = valueTextView.getText().toString();
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        valueTextView.setText(ss.value);
    }

    public static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        String value;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        public SavedState(Parcel source) {
            super(source);
            value = source.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeString(value);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
                    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new SavedState(in);
                    }

                    public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new SavedState[size];
                    }
                };
    }
}
```

Child view XML in my custom view

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/minusButton"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/valueTextView" />
```