# Custom component (edit text) value replicating with other view of the screen when Fragment reopen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have created custom view by extending LinearLayout, Its work as per the requirement. However when I re-open fragment at that time, last edit text value copied to all other edit text available into the same screen.

[Here is the custom component](http://app/src/main/java/com/devdigital/fragmentstatemanager/components/NewEditText.kt)

[Here is issue](https://youtu.be/ju3qKB79yrw)

Sample Code of Fragment:

```
class DashboardFragment : BaseFragment() {

    companion object {
        var count = 0
        val KEY_EXTRA_TITLE = "key.extra.title"
        fun newInstance(message: String) = DashboardFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(KEY_EXTRA_TITLE, message)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onFragmentCreate() {

        arguments?.let {
            mRootView.tvTitle.text = it.getString(KEY_EXTRA_TITLE)
        }

        mRootView.btnNextChild.setOnClickListener {
            FragmentHolder.dashboardFragmentHolder.nextChild(newInstance("Next Child ${++count}"))
        }

        mRootView.newFirstName.setHint("First Name")
        mRootView.newSecondName.setHint("Last Name")
    }

    override fun getResourceId() = R.layout.fragment_dashboard


}
```

Here is Custom component Code:

```
class NewEditText : LinearLayout {

    lateinit var edtBox: AppCompatEditText
    lateinit var tvHint: AppCompatTextView

    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(mContext: Context) : super(mContext) {
        init(mContext)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        init(context)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(mContext: Context) {
        val mRootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
            R.layout.component_newedit_text, this, true
        )

        edtBox = mRootView.edtBox
        tvHint = mRootView.tvHint

    }

    fun setHint(hint: String) {
        tvHint.text = hint
    }

    fun getHint() = tvHint.hint

}
```

[Sample Project code](https://github.com/hitesh-dhamshaniya/FragmentStateManager)

Comment: You're going to have to handle saving and restoring your custom `View`'s state yourself. Briefly, you'll need to set `android:saveEnabled="false"` on the `<EditText>`, and override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in `NewEditText`. Here's a _very_ similar post where we just recently did the same thing, except in Java (though I'm sure you can translate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/57533532.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and reply, I defensively check that out.

Answer (score 3):

After spending long time to solve that problem, I have found below solution. When you deal with custom edit text and provide id to edit text, than edit text will preserve the state and when enter values it will duplicate it. So do not assign ID to edittext use below code to find edittext.

```
/**
 * @param view ViewGroup
 * @return AppCompactEditText
 */
private fun findView(view: ViewGroup): View? {
    for (i in 0 until view.childCount) {
        val childAt = view.getChildAt(i)
        if (childAt is ViewGroup) {
            return findView(childAt)
        } else if (childAt is AppCompatEditText) {
            return childAt
        }
    }
    return null
}

private fun init(mContext: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        this.mContext = mContext
//other code
     inputEditText =
                findView(mRootView!! as ViewGroup) as TextInputEditText
/* inputEditText = mRootView?.findViewById(R.id.edtView) remove edtView id from xml and find it by findView(view) method which is created above */
}
```